# Android listview image and text from mysql using php

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to fetch images and text from mysql using php with this example
[example](http://www.simplylearnprogramming.com/display-image-android-listview/6).

The result from php code is empty, where is the error in this php code?

I store my images in server folder and add links in the database.

```
<?php
    require_once('dbConnect.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM androidosnames";

    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $result = array();

    while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
        array_push($result,array(
            "AndroidNames"=>$res['AndroidNames'],
            "ImagePath"=>$res['ImagePath']
        ));
    }
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: In my log after the app stopped give me this org.json.JSONException: Value   of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Run the code in the browser and see what the output is. Since you copied the code there is a good chance that it works. But what about the dbConnect.php file? Is the error in den DB connection?

Comment: I run it but the arry is empty

Comment: I use dbConnect.php for another php file and it work good

Answer (score 0):

using your code and this dbConnect.php

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'broadcasting', 'broadcasting', 'broadcasting', 3306);
```

and this database information

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `androidosnames` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AndroidNames` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ImagePath` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `androidosnames` (`id`, `AndroidNames`, `ImagePath`) VALUES
    (1, 'myname', '/ports/links');
```

yields following result when executing on command line (`php -f test.php`)

```
{"result":[{"AndroidNames":"myname","ImagePath":"\/ports\/links"}]}
```

So everything works as intended. It looks to me like the information from the database cannot be retrieved in your environment.